# SQLite3 equivalent to mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, sqlite

What's the equivalent in SQLite3 to mysql_num_rows? 
I know SQLite had a similar function call. What I'm doing in PHP is doing a for while fetching an array from the query and counting a variable but I don't like it very much.

Comment: I think that the only solution is the for loop and counting the var, but I'd love to be proven wrong. At least here http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php I can't find anything useful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a changes method that will offer the num rows/affected rows functionality for update/delete methods. For select type queries, you can count the result set or effectively make a second request that will count the result of your previous query (will cost more time to your application). 
For a  "select users where firstname = 'john'" this should look something like this:

SELECT count(*) FROM ( select users where firstname = 'john' ) as tmp;

But it will cost you an extra query and i'm pretty sure that counting the returned result set will be more efficient.

Answer (score -2):

What about the SQL-query called `COUNT`?

Comment: Count is nothing about num_rows. num_rows return the number of result affected or returned by a query. count is a sql aggregate function and won't return you the number of affected rows by the previous update for example.

Comment: Oh, I did not throught about that, so I will recommend http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-num-rows.php

Comment: I believe the poster is referring to http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php . There doesn't appear to be such a function.